# php check if user already connected and watch video

Tags: php

I create php script to users watch video

get video id and user from url

like that

```
http://localhost/CHH.php?id=46&user=1234
```

i want user use url for himself only

now other users can use the same link i want to block others to use the same url.

```
$id = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']);
$user = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['user']);
if ($id == '' OR $user == '') { exit; }

$getuser = mysql_query("select * from users WHERE user = '$user'");
if (mysql_num_rows($getuser) == 0) { exit; }

$getvideo = mysql_query("select * from videos WHERE videoid = '$id' ");
$showvideo = mysql_fetch_array($getvideo);
$url = $showvideo['videourl'];

   header('Location: '.$url);
   die();
```

Comment: watch this https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLfdtiltiRHWF5Rhuk7k4UAU1_yLAZzhWc

Comment: If there is no question

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is to:

- Authenticate your user with a login.
- Store it's ID into a `$_SESSION` variable for example `$_SESSION["userId"]`.
- Compare the `$_GET["id"]` with the stored `$_SESSION["userId"]` variable.
- If they do not match, then redirect to a forbidden page.
- If they match, show him the video.

Comment: user can use only url by his device , he can not connect as web browser . so i use user as code .

Comment: anyway, somehow you need to authenticate the user. if not, then you need to compare the `$_GET['id']` with the ID of user who is using the device. So you need to know the id of the user.

Comment: Are these users recognized only by cookies?

Comment: What kind of device do you talking about? What is intresting to me, you says, he can not connect as web browser. So who to call this http://localhost url?

Comment: device as vlc player and playlist , localhost just as example url . the player use nsplayer , i create user only to every one and use it in url like that CHH.php?id=46&user=1234 . but many people can use the same url , i need to do user for ervery one .

Comment: if you can not get, what user is trying to watch the video, you can not solve this problem, because you can not compare the id in url.

Comment: i can get video id once user choose the video but i can not get if user still watch the video or no, just when user choose video i can get it but redirect user to the video url .

Comment: not the id of video, id of user. again. you can not prevent /allow somebody to see the video, if you do not know the id of the viewer.

Comment: how to know or get the id of the viewer ?

Comment: This is your main problem man. Since, you do not know, how do you want to allow only a specified user? It seems like: "Hey, i want to allow to see this video is only for John. Who see this video now? - Don't know. Maybe John, maybe Sarah." You can only allow it only to John, if you know, John seeing the video or Sarah? If Sarah, redirect her to a forbidden page, if John, show him the video. Understand?

Comment: In this case, i think, you need to redesign your concept. Somehow, users need to be authenticated to know, is it the right person? Do you want to deploy you app on a desktop or mobile device with no net connection?

Comment: client can use the authenticated from any other devices and i will not know that . can i get mac address from the client player ? what details can i get from the client ? all players use as web browser . i only can get user agent .

Comment: Mac address is not an optoin, because if user use the web thorugh a router, you will get the address of the router. Is it in a local netnwork? the best way, if you create a webpage for this, a login procedure, and show the video in the browser through a plugin. i have no more idea.